# Python: Cannot debug using vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am new to python as well as anaconda, I installed and setup everything including environment variables.
then i opened up vs code and typed in

```
print("hello world")
```

and tried debugging. 
I did not get any output and got a couple of timeout on debugger.
this is what was on terminal after i ran the debugger:

> (base) C:\Users\Arun>cd e:\pythontutorials && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && E:\Python\pythonw.exe c:\Users\Arun.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.11.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 62293 e:\pythontutorials\firstprogram.py "

Comment: what does `python --version` show from your terminal?

Comment: it shows Python 3.7.1

Comment: open up your settings `ctrl + ,` search for python path and change the python configuration > python path to `python3`

Comment: as u told, i went to python configurations and i saw Python: Python Path
Path to Python, you can use a custom version of Python by modifying this setting to include the full path.

E:\Python\pythonw.exe
i didn't understand the rest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is a path error. As I have encountered in the past VS Code doesn't allow you to run python commands from its terminal unless its paths are also set in the system variables. Do recheck these.

Comment: hello, I just tried to execute the file directly from terminal and it seems to work. ie, python firstprogram.py

Comment: E:\Python;E:\Python\Library\mingw-w64\bin;E:\Python\Library\usr\bin;E:\Python\Library\bin;E:\Python\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin btw i installed python on e drive

Answer (score -1):

Install Python by microsoft, seems you already have

open up your settings ctrl + , search for python path and change the python configuration > python path to python3

From your debug tab, click on settings icon and add the code below to your launch.json file, save it and make sure it is selected as your config in the debug tab.

```
   {        "name": "Python: Current File (Default Debug)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "none"

        }
```

If all goes well, you should be able to debug from the DEBUG CONSOLE` not the terminal

Comment: sir, i didn't understand what you meant by change the python configuration > python path to python3. i did reach till python configurations > python path but where to change it to python3

Comment: If your path is already set, do not change it. try setting up your debug config next.